# How to determine the last indicator value

Tags: pine-script

I've got an indicator which draws pivot highs and lows on a chart:

```
leftBars  = input(3)
rightBars = input(3)
ph = pivothigh(high, leftBars, rightBars)
pl = pivotlow(low, leftBars, rightBars)
```

How can I determine which of both happened at last (to set that as current indicator value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable for this purpose. `pivothigh()` and `pivotlow()` return `NaN` if there is no pivot at that point. So, you can check if the value is not `Nan`, which means there is a new pivot point.

```
//@version=4
study("Find last pivot", overlay=false)
leftBars  = input(3)
rightBars = input(3)

var lastPivot = 0    // Use "var" so it will keep its latest value
ph = pivothigh(high, leftBars, rightBars)
pl = pivotlow(low, leftBars, rightBars)

if (not na(ph))      // New pivot high
    lastPivot := 1
else
    if (not na(pl))  // New pivot low
        lastPivot := -1

// Now, you can check lastPivot's value to see what type of pivot you had last
// lastPivot = 1  -> Pivot high
// lastPivot = -1 -> Pivot low

plot(series=lastPivot, color=color.red, linewidth=2)
```

[image]

As you can see, `lastPivot`'s value alternates between 1 and -1 and its value stays the same until there is a new pivot.

Comment: Do you also know how I can compare the prices of any PH or PL in the series (to find out if there is an uptrend or downtrend)?

Comment: What does your compare algortihm look like? Maybe ask a new question.